# mmap() returns same pointer twice

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, x86-64, mmap

I have run into a problem with a page allocator that I cannot wrap my head around. The program is run on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 and the g++ --version output says "g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2".

My issue is that sometimes, I receive the same pointer from a mmap() call that I already have received from earlier call without that previous pointer ever having been mmunmap():ed. In one debugging sessions for example I successfully allocated 2097152 bytes and got the pointer 0x7fffaa398000, and then some time later with a bunch other allocations in between I successfully allocated 12288 bytes for the very same pointer, 0x7fffaa398000. The allocator then proceeds to assert because book keeping notices this double entry.

The call looks like this:

```
void *p = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Is it possible for the pointer to get deallocated in some other way other than munmap()?

Comment: How do you know you get the same pointer twice? How do you detect it? Have you tried adding some tracing, i.e. some debug output when you call `mmap` (and `unmap`) to make sure you're not calling `unmap` on a pointer you shouldn't unmap, as well as seeing what `mmap` actually returns?

Comment: I have print statements after each call, also there is only one place where mmap() is called and one where unmap() is called in the whole codebase. The prints look like: fprintf(stderr, "Page   alloc: %p, size: %d\n", p, size); right after mmap() and fprintf(stderr, "Page dealloc: %p, size: %d\n", p, size); after munmap(). This generates a huge amount of logging of course but through this I can see that the pointer is never actually deallocated before being allocated again.

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of your code where you saw the problem. mmap should never return the same pointer without  some munmap in between.

Comment: I think that you should use `strace -e mmap,munmap ./yourprogram`, it will give you more reliable results.

Comment: It's a bit difficult since it's a huge machinery, but this last crash happened as it entered a resource loading thread. Is it possible that threading affects the behavior of mmap()? I also notice the page allocator itself is not thread safe but the allocators using it are.

Comment: It actually is thread safe, it was in a piece of boilerplate code that other platform implementations get wrapped in. I am trying to reproduce the issue with strace but it's tricky.

Comment: Here is output from an strace run with the crash: http://pastebin.com/a5V7Z1NY In this case it is the pointer 0x7f8eeac35000 at the end that was allocated earlier with a larger size and then allocated again with a smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're coercing map addresses, are you sure you're not conflicting with anything?  If you're specifying an address for the mapping, any preexisting mapping at that location will be discarded and overwritten.

Look for a `munmap()` call that unmaps memory located **before** the pointer that gets duplicated, but where it's close enough that the amount of memory unmapped covers the address in question.  I'd venture to say it's likely a pointer and/or a mapping length is getting corrupted.  If you "*over*"-`munmap()` and/or *misalign*-`munmap()`, memory will still get unmapped but it won't correspond to the blocks you allocated.  Run your process under `strace`, and trace **only** `mmap()` and `munmap()` calls to minimize the impact in case it's caused by a timing issue.  Look for `munmap()` calls where the address plus length covers the pointer you see mapped twice.

Comment: I made simple python script to parse my crash dump from runnign strace (http://pastebin.com/a5V7Z1NY), but couldn't find a case where `base < 0x7f8eeac35000 and base + size > 0x7f8eeac35000` unfortunately.

Comment: Can you figure out what the process address space looks like **before** the bad `mmap()` call?  If you can recreate the problem consistently enough that you know which `mmap()` call is going to return a duplicate address, what does the output from `pmap` show if it's run immediately before the suspect `mmap()` call is made?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you would need to check that there are no overlaps, try this or similar. Also there might be a max you can mmap.

warning untested code::

```
std::set<decltype(void *)> mySet;

// On mmap

void *p = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
assert(!(p & 0xfff));
auto pp = p;
while (size > 0) {
  if (mySet.count(pp) {
    printf("bug %p\n", pp);
  mySet.insert(pp);
  pp += 4096;
  size -= 4096;
}  

// On unmap

res = unmap(p, size); 
assert(!(p & 0xfff));
auto pp = p;
while (size > 0) {
  if (!mySet.count(pp) {
    printf("bug %p, size %d\n", pp, mySet.size()); // %d or ld???
  mySet.erase(pp);
  pp += 4096;
  size -= 4096;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `mmap()` call is usually passed to the file descriptor/driver, in your case `-1` (I assume that you normally use a valid descriptor). 
My suggestion is, that you look at the code of the driver, especially the `mmap()` function of the driver and verify the functionality.

Additionally look at the `dmesg` output if there are any error/warnings regarding the driver.

Comment: I am not well-versed with drivers. dmesg doesn't seem to report anything about mmap.

Comment: What kind of driver is it (maybe the name)? What kind of memory are you trying to map (DMA, MMIO)?

Comment: He's using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` to get zero-initialized pages for an allocator, not to actually map a file.  In this case, the man page says `fd` is either ignored or required to be `-1`, depending on what POSIX system you're on.